# StringBuilder Append and AppendLine give different results for Enum

Tags: .net, append, stringbuilder

When using a string builder, I get expected results from the append and append line functions when using an enum is the input, but when the enum is boxed the append line and append function give differing results.

Can anyone tell me what may be behind this?

Code output:

```
Append Enum: 1
Append Enum To String: One
Append Line Enum: 1
Append Line Enum To String: One
Append Object: One
Append Object To String: One
Append Line Object: 1
Append Line Object To String: One
```

Code:

```
Public Enum eTest
    One = 1
    Two = 2
End Enum

Sub Main()
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim x = eTest.One
    sb.Append("Append Enum: ").Append(x).AppendLine()
    sb.Append("Append Enum To String: ").Append(x.ToString()).AppendLine()
    sb.Append("Append Line Enum: ").AppendLine(x)
    sb.Append("Append Line Enum To String: ").AppendLine(x.ToString())

    Dim o As Object = x
    sb.Append("Append Object: ").Append(o).AppendLine()
    sb.Append("Append Object To String: ").Append(o.ToString()).AppendLine()
    sb.Append("Append Line Object: ").AppendLine(o)
    sb.Append("Append Line Object To String: ").AppendLine(o.ToString())

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())


    '===============================
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of the file to get rid of the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
sb.Append("Append Object: ").Append(o).AppendLine()
```

causes `o.ToString()` to be appended to the instance of `StringBuilder` and that is the difference. Of course, that call just passes through to the boxed instance of your enum and this is why you see `One` for this invocation.

This is because you are invoking the overload [`StringBuilder.Append(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5atxc566.aspx) which will just invoke `o.ToString()` on the passed in instance of object. This is explicitly in the documentation:

> The `Append` method calls the `Object.ToString` method to get the string representation of `value`. If `value` is `null`, no changes are made to the `StringBuilder` object.

On the other hand, when you call

```
sb.Append("Append Enum: ").Append(x).AppendLine()
```

where `x` is an instance of an enum, `x` will be implicitly converted to an instance of `int` which will call the overload [`StringBuilder.Append(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wt5x6h.aspx).

Note that this is specific to VB.NET. C# will not implicitly convert `x` to an `int` when choosing which overload of `StringBuilder.Append` to invoke; it will invoke `StringBuilder.Append(object)`.

Comment: That part I think I am ok with, the curious piece to me is the difference in output of .Append(o) and .AppendLine(o), which emits "One" and "1" respectively. I would expect the call to both functions with the boxed object to give the same result.

Comment: This is VB.NET. There are only two overloads of `StringBuilder.AppendLine`. The first is `AppendLine()` and the second is `AppendLine(string)`. The first can not apply here. So, it is the first that applies. So now we are passing a variable declared as `object` to a method receiving a parameter of type `string`. VB.NET will add a call to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(object)` which will detect that `o` is convertible to an instance of `Int32` and will then invoke `Int32.ToString`. Add `Option Strict On` and this won't happen. It doesn't happen in C#, as well.

Comment: Correction. Change "The first can not apply here. So, it is the first that applies." to "The first can not apply here. So, it is the second that applies."